# Java Recursion Count Parameter

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree, depth-first-search

I am writing a recursive call to see if two nodes (n & m) are contained within a subtree in a binary tree. Here is the function:

```
public static boolean containsNodes(int n, int m, TreeNode node, int count){
    if(node == null) return false;
    if( count == 2) return true;
    if(node.getData() == m || node.getData() == n){
        count++;
    }
    return containsNodes(n, m, node.getLeft(), count) || 
           containsNodes(n, m, node.getRight(), count);

}
```

It looks likes count is never getting updated in later calls even though the condition `node.getData() == m || node.getData() == n` is true'. Why is this so?

Comment: Consider a simple 3 node tree (A parent with 2 children). The parent node has one left and one right node. Even if the data is 'n' and 'm' respectively for left and right, this method will fail since the count is independent on each branch. You might be better off passing an object containing the count instead of a primitive for determining the count since pass-by-value is causing the problem here. Perhaps I've misunderstood how you want it to work though.

Answer (score 1):

This code will return true even if you find `n` or `m` twice. Return a "mask" in place of `boolean`, and set bit zero when you find `m` and bit 1 when you find `n`. Add a wrapper that returns `true` for the "mask" of 3, and `false` for everything else:

```
public static boolean containsNodes(int n, int m, TreeNode node) {
    return containsNodesMask(n, m, node, 0) == 3;
}
private static int containsNodesMask(int n, int m, TreeNode node, int mask) {
    if (node == null) return mask;
    if (node.getData() == m) mask |= 2;
    if (node.getData() == n) mask |= 1;
    if (mask == 3) return mask; // Short-circuit
    mask = containsNodes(n, m, node.getLeft(), mask);
    if (mask == 3) return mask; // Short-circuit again
    return containsNodes(n, m, node.getRight(), mask);
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work; as above, consider a tree s.t. `n`, `m` are the left and right (respectively) children of a single parent node `p`.